# FileHelpers source code

Tags: c#, .net, filehelpers

I would like to add to FileHelpers an Excel parsing engine based on the NPOI library, but I can't find anywhere the source code of the 2.9.x version.

Anyone can point me where I can contrbute to the project?

Answer (score 8):

The last source code is on github

https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers

Welcome to the project, I'm a bit out but would be great some help to reactivate the 3.0 release :)

Thanks !!!