# What is the latest production-ready version of the FileHelpers .NET library and where is it?

Tags: c#, .net, filehelpers

The SourceForge page - [www.filehelpers.net](http://www.filehelpers.net) - was last updated in 2007, and no downloads are available.

The Github repo - [github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/) - looks recent but the last tagged release is 2.1

There is a NuGet package - [www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers-Stable](http://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers-Stable/) - but it is two years old and furthermore does not belong to the main developer, Marcos Meli.  There is a competing NuGet package - [www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers](http://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers/) - tagged as 2.0.0 and owned by Marcos Meli, but that code is 6 years old.

There are [TeamCity builds available](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewType.html?buildTypeId=bt66&guest=1).  There is a successful development build tagged as 2.9.16.

Which of the above should I use for a production ready project?  Or is the latest production-ready version somewhere else?

**EDIT**

I cloned from github master, but it didn't build - riddled with errors.  I went through and set the .NET version to 4.5 on all subprojects and fixed a few imports and got the wizard to run, but there were still a couple of dozen warnings.  So Github head is obviously not the production-ready version.

**EDIT 2**

Now the version **3.1 is production ready**, and the GitHub repository is up to date and using CI for continuos buils
Download latest version from [www.filehelpers.net](http://www.filehelpers.net)

Comment: It looks like something's happening with Filehelpers - there were commits to the Github repo as recently as June 15 2014. I was able to clone, then build and run the wizard without any hitches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest production ready version of the library is **3.1.2**

You can download it on

- NuGet: [www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers/](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers/)
- GitHub:
  [github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/releases/](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/releases/)
- Source
  code: [github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers)
- Analyzer: [www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers.Analyzer/](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers.Analyzer/)

New Home Page:

[image: FileHelpers Home Page]

Comment: Cool.  I'm no longer doing .NET development, but I'll pass this on to the developers who took over my project.  Thanks so much for your work - you saved me a heck of a lot of time and bother.

Answer (score 3):

On NuGet there are two versions: [2.0.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers/) and [2.9.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers-Stable/).

The 2.0.0.0 version was developed between 2005 and 2007 and has plenty of documentation [here](http://www.filehelpers.com/).

The 2.9.9 version is more recent and includes some new features (e.g., the `FieldOrder` attribute - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8833322/1077279)) and some breaking changes (e.g., the `AfterReadRecord` and `BeforeReadRecord` events have changed signature to use generics). Development seems to have stalled sometime in 2012.

Both of these are stable and we use them in different production enterprise applications with no problems.

According to [Marcos's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525793/filehelpers-source-code), the latest version is here: http://filehelpers.svn.sourceforge.net/. However that answer is over a year old.

Comment: A note: when I need to see the source code, I tend to use .NET reflector with the 2.9.9 binaries.

Comment: I went ahead and used the 2.9.9 version from NuGet.  Worked great.  There was a change in the annotations for skipping/unavailable fields in fixed length.  The brilliant part is that I can add field conversions/calculations as getter properties and then throw the whole thing at Massive as a an IEnumerable of POCOs.

Comment: Marcos Meli is actively developing FileHelpers again! See his answer to this same question.